# Scheduled task status

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

How to check last run result of scheduled task? We used "schtasks /query" command. But it didn't displayed our manually created scheduled task status. We don't want system scheduled task status. Only manually created scheduled task results are needed. (EX: scheduled task1: Task completed successfully Or Scheduled task1: Task completed with errors etc). Also can we create a log file with results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got one solution. Run this command in cmd.
schtasks /query /tn "\Alarm Clock" /v /fo list |findstr /b "Last TaskName Next Status">>"%userprofile%\desktop\Tasks.txt"
It gives only required information. But the thing is we have to specify each scheduled task name in command